# Reduce with enumerate Python

Tags: python, lambda, reduce, enumerate

I'm trying to get product of list where every element is multiplied by its index + 1. I tried with reduce and enumerate

```
value = reduce(lambda a, b: (a[0]+1)*a[1]*b[1], enumerate(list))
```

but it gives `TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable`.
Is it possible to do it in one line?

**Editv2**

example of list `[1,2,3]`

desire output `list[0]*1 * list[1]*2 * list[2]*3 = 36`

Comment: Can you give an example list and the result you want?

Comment: there is no positions for 'a' it might be single number check it once

Comment: Your lambda returns a single number which is fed as parameter a in the next call to lambda.

Comment: You clearly want the **sum** of those products! Otherwise you will always get 0, if multiply index 0 somewhere in there.

Comment: Why not just `sum` and a generator expression: `sum(index * value for index, value in enumerate(data))`?

Comment: nom i clarified what i mean

Comment: `1*1 + 2*2 + 3*3 == 14` no?

Comment: i wanted product not sum

Comment: Instead of sum do numpy.prod([i*v for i, v in enumerate(lst, 1)])

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simplest:

```
lst = [1,2,3]  # do not shadow `list`
sum(i*v for i, v in enumerate(lst, 1))
# 14
```

Your reduce approach fails as it returns an `int` which is not the same type that it expects as its two inputs (`tuple`). You could do it with:

```
reduce(lambda a, b: (a[0]*a[1] + b[0]*b[1], 1), enumerate(lst, 1))[0]
# 14
```

Note the `(..., 1)` structure of the lambda expression where the `1` serves as an auxiliary factor for the next step.

**Update:** As you actually want the homogenous product of all the elements of your nested iterable, the following is simpler:

```
from itertools import chain
from operator import mul

reduce(mul, chain(*enumerate(lst, 1)))
# 36
```

Comment: OP wants index + 1.

Comment: @blueteeth Adapted ;)

Comment: that's what I tried to achive .Still I wanted the product not sum but it is enough to replace '+'  with '*' and works, so thank you for help

Comment: Instead of sum do numpy.prod([i*v for i, v in enumerate(lst, 1)])

Answer (score 1):

The trick is to make a new list and multiply through it.

Create a new list where a number at index *i* is `i*list[i]`, indexing starting with 1:

```
>>> new_list = [a*b for a, b in enumerate(list, 1)]
>>> new_list
[1, 4, 9]
```

and multiply over your new list:

```
>>> reduce((lambda x, y: x*y), new_list)
36
```

In one line:

```
>>> reduce((lambda x, y: x*y), [a*b for a, b in enumerate(list, 1)])
36
```

Hope it helped :)

Note: Answer edited to meet OP's changes.

Answer (score 0):

```
ans = sum(i * x for i, x in enumerate(list, 1))
```

Not exactly what you are asking for, but it gives the desired result.